# A new (?) infinitely nested radical equals $1$

Tags: reference-request, nested-radicals

Let $x$ be a real number such that $x\ge{0}$, then

$$1=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2}}+1}{2}}+1}{2}}+1}{2}}+...$$

At least I haven't seen it on the internet.

**Questions: a) Is this known?, b) Does this formula generalize any well-known nested radical?**

Comment: This is based on the iteration $$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{x_n+1}{2}}$$ converging to $1$ for every non-negative start value $x_0$

Comment: Do you know about [*A chronology of continued square roots and other continued compositions, through the year 2016*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06139) by Dixon J. Jones (2018)? If not, then for most any historical question about continued radicals you'll want to begin by looking in this historical survey manuscript. By the way, you don't even need to visit a library for most anything mentioned before about 1910 -- just google its title in google-books.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f:[-b/a,\infty)$ with $a\gt0,$ $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sqrt{ax+b}.$ We can define the sequence family $s[f]$ such that $s[f]_{n+1}=f(s[f]_n).$ Define $f^n$ such that $f^{n+1}=f\circ{f^n}.$ Then $s[f]_n=f^n(s[f]_0).$ The nested radical in question is then equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}s[f]_n.$ The fixed points of $f$ are given by the solutions of the equation $x=\sqrt{ax+b}.$ $x=\sqrt{ax+b}$ is equivalent to $ax=a\sqrt{ax+b}=(ax+b)-b=\sqrt{ax+b}^2-b=a\sqrt{ax+b},$ which, with the caveat that $\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b\gt0,$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{ax+b}^2-a\sqrt{ax+b}-b=0=\left(\sqrt{ax+b}-\frac{a}2\right)^2-\left[\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b\right]=\left[\sqrt{ax+b}-\frac{a}2-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}\right]\left[\sqrt{ax+b}-\frac{a}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}\right].$

In the case that $\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}-\frac{a}2\gt0,$ $\frac{a}2-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}$ is not a fixed point, so only $\frac{a}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}$ is a fixed point. This is the case when $b\gt0.$ In that case, you would use the monotone convergence theorem to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s[f]_n=\frac{a}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}2\right)^2+b}.$$ So this indeed generalize other well-known results. For example, if $a=1$ and $b=1,$ then $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}.$$